# On Branch master git status is showing nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

Tags: git, github

I would like to commit but, whenever I am entering git commit -a -m "Initial commit. Added a gitignore file and a README file.

Git status showing as Nothing to commit ((create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

```
Git init
git add .
git commit -----------------
```

Where am I lacking? Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you added readme.md to gitignore ? if so then remove it from there

Comment: I haven't added readme.md to gitignore. I have created a separate file for Readme.md

Comment: What does `git status --ignore` tell you? Can you show us a directory listing?

Comment: It is showing same like  same: On Branch, master git status is showing nothing to commit (create/copy files and use “git add” to track). Also, .git is not showing in ATOM

Comment: @SubhenduRoy See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
> ```

That means you are in a brand new local repo, with no file in it.
You need to add files in that folder first, *then* you can add and commit.

The full sequence would be:

```
git init mynewrepo
cd mynewrepo
git remote add origin https://github.com/<user>/mynewrepo
# write files (README, LICENCE, ...)
git add .
git commit -m "work"
git push -u origin master
```

---

Note that, as an alternative, you can create a new repository on GitHub side, directly with a README.

Once that is done, you can clone it:

```
git clone https://github.com/<user>/mynewrepo
cd mynewrepo
# add other files
git add .
git commit -m "work"
git push -u origin master
```

Answer (score 8):

If in someone's case even after using `git add .` this problem persists, then this may be useful.

For people like me working on python, if you are creating virtual environment using

```
virtualenv .
```

in the same folder, then it will automatically modify **.gitignore** file and hence it will look like:

```
# created by virtualenv automatically
*
```

Which is may be the source of problem in many cases.
Removing * may solve problem.

Conclusion: Try checking your **.gitignore** file

Answer (score 0):

You have to commit a file ! If you try too commit a repository you'll have this error :"nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)" too.
If you want to create a empty repository you have to create a file.gitkeep in your repository.